# Uncertainty of the area of a Gaussian curve atop a linear background

Tags: normal-distribution, nonlinear-optimization, covariance

I have some data from a counting-based spectroscopy experiment.  Each data point is an (Energy, Rate) pair.

I'd like to fit the dataset to a Gaussian curve (signal) plus a slope (background):

$$
I(E) = A e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(E-E_0)^2}{\sigma^2}} + m(E-E_0) + b
$$

The fit parameters are $A, E_0, m, b$.  I'd like to deduce the rate and associated uncertainty of signal events.

I use Mathematica to perform the fit.  I use the inverse-variance of each data point as that point's weight.  I get fit parameters and associated uncertainties from the fit

$$
A = 0.58 \pm 0.05
$$
$$
E_0 = 1212.70 \pm 0.17 
$$
$$
\sigma = 2.24 \pm 0.15 
$$
$$
m = -0.0013 \pm 0.0007 
$$
$$
b = 0.101 \pm 0.008
$$

The uncertainty in the fit parameters are the square root of the diagonal elements of covariance matrix.

Now, the area of the signal peak is $Area = A\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$, and the rate of signal events is $R = \frac{Area}{W}$, where $W$ is the uniform energy bin width.  For the data shown here ($W = 0.399$), this produces $R = 8.103 Hz$.

But what is the uncertainty of this rate?  I could use simple propagation of errors and I get

$$
\Delta_R = R\sqrt{(\frac{\Delta_A}{A})^2+(\frac{\Delta_s}{s})^2} = 0.848 Hz
$$

But this doesn't take into account the uncertainty in the background!  How do I account for the uncertainty in the background when calculating the area of the Gaussian peak?  Or do the variances of the fit parameters for the area - namely $(\Delta_A)^2$ and $(\Delta_s)^2$ - already contain contributions owing to the uncertainties in the background parameters?

Many thanks!